# Getting Methods from another Class in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, addition

I'm new to Java, so please bear with me if this is the stupidest thing you have ever heard.

So, basically I'm creating a form in Java. When it is submitted, it is validated, and if there in an error, I want the specific form item to turn red. I've managed to do so by calling the method setAsError()

```
public void setAsError(){
    this.setBackground(new Color(230,180,180));
}
```

But the problem is, my form items (Includes Text fields, Combo Boxes and other swing classes) already extends the Java components.

```
public class KComboBox extends JComboBox {

public KComboBox(String[] s){
    super(s);
    //There's other stuff in here too
}
```

I want to add the setAsError() method to my form items. I realize that I could individually add the method to all the necessary classes, but this seems a bit odd for OO programming.

In any case, the end result should be, when I do

```
myFormItem.setAsError()
```

the field should turn red.

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void setAsError(JComponent component){
    if(component instanceof JTextField){
    JTextField field =  (JTextField) component;
    field.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }else if(component instance of JTextArea){
    JTextArea area = (JTextArea) component;
    area.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

By simply adding a `JComponent` argument to your `setError()`, you can achieve what you want.

Now, say you found that the user has left the 'name' field in the form empty.
When he/she clicks the submit button, I am sure you are checking for empty condition.

```
if(nameField.getText().equals("")){
    this.setAsError(nameField);
}
```

Now, I am pretty sure you need to reset the background color to what it was once you found out the error has gone away from that field so I suggest you also make a `resetError(JComponent compo)` where you reset the color to default.
Now, background color can differ from Windows to Mac to Ubuntu. What you need to do is that get the background color, at the start of the application, and store it.
When the error condition is gone, set it to the default value you stored.

Comment: Try to avoid `instanceof`

Comment: @MaximShoustin then the OP will have to resort to `getClass().getName()` :)

Comment: This seems interesting, never saw an answer like this while searching.

Quick question though, in this solution, into which class would the setAsError() method go?

I'd like to do this in a way so that there are no duplicates.

Comment: In the `JFrame` class :)

Comment: `setBackground(Color)` is a method of `Component`, so the `instanceof` checks and casts are useless and simply duplicate code in a manner worse than putting a method into each class a la Maxim Shoustin's solution.  You also can't put this `setAsError` message in the `JFrame` class, because you can't edit that class.  If indeed all you need is `setBackground(Color)`, create a utility class to hold `public static void setAsError(JComponent c) { c.setBackground(Color.RED); }`, or if you might need to customize some but not all components use a single `if (c instanceof ErrorItf)`.

Comment: @Jeremy If the OP wants to do more than just set color, casts are needed :)

Comment: @LittleChild if the OP wants to do more than just set color, then the OP is better off with an interface and a custom `setAsError` that does the right thing for the appropriate class than with a long chain of `if instanceof` that defeat the purpose of OO and obscures extensibility.  That is, either the code is shared, whereupon a (`static`) helper method that only needs to know that the argument is a `(J)Component` is enough, or the code isn't shared, so it may as well be specialized within the affected class.

Answer (score 3):

Java supports multiple interface inheritance, which allows an object to inherit many method signatures from different interfaces.

So create new `interface` with `setAsError` method add implement for all relevant classes.

Something like:

```
public interface ErrorItf {
 public void setAsError();
}
```

After, add it to your class:

```
public class KComboBox extends JComboBox implements ErrorItf{

...

  @override
  public void setAsError(){
    this.setBackground(new Color(230,180,180));
  }

}
```

Now instead to call your class, call by interface, like:

```
ErrorItf element = getComboBox();
element.setAsError();
```

When you send a message to an object (aka `element.setAsError()`) even though you don’t know what specific type it is `JComboBox` or `JTextarea` ... . That’s called **polymorphism**

*As a side note, example how interface can help in your case*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, if I do it using interfaces, won't I have to individually write the method in all the classes that is implemented by it? I was wondering if there was a way to avoid that.

Comment: @KaneelDias Have a look at my answer on how to do it without interfaces :-)

Comment: Are your classes have the same method implementation?

Comment: Why you try to avoid interfaces?

Comment: It's not a huge problem. I just prefer to not have any duplicate code running about (since then, in all classes which implement the interface, I will have to write the method seperately).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to create an interface. Just write

```
Interface SetAsErrorable{
    void setAsError();
}
```

In global scope (or in its own file). Then add to all your form item classes `implements SetAsErrorable`. IE `KComboBox extendsJComboBox implements SetAsErrorable{`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like using an interface would be good...

```
public interface errorInterface {
 public setAsError();
}

public class KComboBox extends JComboBox implements errorInterface {

 @Override
 setAsError() {
    this.setBackground(new Color(230,180,180));
 }
}
```